# Angular 2 adal single token for multiple endpoints

Tags: angular, adal

I have created a simple angular spa project where I use ng2-adal library for authentication and authorization. The library has a method acquireToken that returns a single token for a single endpoint you have specified in its parameter and that works fine. I use it to make REST API calls. As I have multiple API endpoints I need to define an array of those endpoints for which a single token will be generated that I will use for all my REST API calls.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call multiple APIs using the same Access Token .A single access token issued by azure ad is for a certain resource/api endpoint . When API receives an Access Token, it will verify that the audience value is correct and reject any tokens intended for a different audience.

ADAL for JavaScript will help you get token for different resource , you should firstly config the endpoints property . When acquiring token for different resource , ADAL JS uses a hidden iframe to drive a UX-less authentication that leverages the presence of that cookie to get new tokens from Azure AD via implicit flow.

Comment: This is not correct. You can query for one token for multiple endpoints. Look at original Microsoft example inside Azure AD Authentication library (ADAL) for JavaScript. endpoints paramterar is array, example on - https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js . I have beein using it for years on AngularJS 1. But I do not have a clue for ng2-adal library and their support on multiple endpoints.

Comment: @HrvojeKusulja , No , op wants to use a single token to access  multiple endpoints.  Yes , endpoints paramterar is array , but it doesn't mean you can use microsoft graph api's access token to access azure ad graph api . Your understanding is not correct .

Comment: If I want to use ADAL and one token for accessing SharePoint Online and myCustomBackendAADApp this is possible with single token. What is wrong with that?

Comment: You could login `myCustomBackendAADApp`  with azure ad user credential using adal , and acquiring an access token to access sharepoint rest api . The access token is  used to access protected resources , in your scenario is sharepoint online endpoint . That is one single endpoint , if you use that access token to call microsoft graph api , then it wouldn't work .

Comment: That is problem and limitation of MS Graph API, all other Azure AD Apps / tokens, including MS Office 365 and custom AAD Apps with their endpoints,  works with the single token for multiple endpoints. So, how to modify ng2-adal library to support this array for endpoint which is also nativity available in MS ADAL JavaScript.

Comment: That is not limitation of MS Graph API . An access token issued from azure ad ,can only access one resource which matches `aud` claim in access token . Your understanding is not correct . Please read more about [Azure AD token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims) . With ADAL in javascript ,it will require a new access token if current token in cache doesn't match the resource which user want to access .

Comment: Ok, so if I need to use several endpoints, by Azure AD design, I need to acquire several tokens. And ADAL for JavaScript SDK does this for me automatically?

Comment: If you need several endpoints ,yes , you need to acquire different tokens . ADAL for JavaScript will help you get token for different resource , that's why you should config the endpointsADAL JS uses a hidden iframe to drive a UX-less authentication that leverages the presence of that cookie to get new tokens from Azure AD via implicit flow.

Comment: ok, can you modify your answer in more details like you did on these comments, so I can give you thumbs up here?